# Будет ли когда-нибудь в словарях этимология глагола "гуглить"?

Tags: словарь

Просто интересно, внесут ли этот глагол в словари ввиду его распространенности. Убежден, что предсказать невозможно, однако интересно услышать Ваши мнения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В словари записывают настоящие слова. Я слово "гуглить" настоящим словом не считаю, поэтому мне будет очень жаль когда его всё-же, под напором общей тенденции, запишут в словари. :)

Comment: Да, словом его не назовешь. :)

Comment: А как его назвать?

Comment: Не знаю. Это скорее название компании, нежели слово. Хотя и название тоже считается словом, однако это слово является именем собственным, поэтому, думаю, не внесут его никогда в словарь.

Comment: Интересно ещё, как склонять такой глагол... такая несуразица получается. :) Насколько легче сказать "посмотреть в гугле", или даже "залесть в гугл". В английском тоже сейчас распространён глагол to google, но там хотя бы его склонять не надо, по ушам не так режет когда его используют. А когда говорят по русски - и слова-то такого нету, и получается оно коверканое какое-то, вообще не понятно, почему его используют.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос интересен. И вот почему: этимологию доброй половины слов проследить сейчас практически невозможно по той простой причине, что современники этих слов, знавшие достоверно о том, как они были образованы, не оставили нам чётких сообщений. Сейчас же, дабы уберечь наших дальних потомков от горячих споров в будущем, естественно, не было бы лишним, вносить такие понятия, как гуглить, в словари.

Comment: Как думаете, можно ли назвать этот глагол интернациональным?

Comment: Именно этот глагол - вряд ли. Корень - возможно, но суффиксы здесь типично русские!

Comment: Сложно сказать даже. Сочетание oo читается как "у" на английском. Я думаю, что каждый человек произносил такое слово, как гугл.